# SQL - Change row/column structure of existing query

Tags: sql

I'm a die hard Excel VBA fan and having to make the transition to a very basic SQL based piece of software. I have managed to adapt an existing query to my needs (still not sure how !) but I could do with some help to further tweek it :)

The query is:
    `PARAMETERS [Date From] DateTime, [Date To] DateTime, [Site Group] Text;


    SELECT Contacts.Name, DataProfile.Date, DataProfile.TotalUnits


    FROM (Lookup INNER JOIN Groups ON Lookup.Lookup_Id = Groups.Lookup_Id) INNER JOIN (Contacts INNER JOIN (Points INNER JOIN DataProfile ON Points.Id = DataProfile.Point_Id) ON Contacts.Id = Points.Contacts_Id) ON Groups.Link_Id = Contacts.Id


    WHERE (((Lookup.Lookup_Name)=[Site Group]) AND ((DataProfile.Date) Between [Date From] And [Date To]) AND ((Points.Type)='Electricity') AND ((DataProfile.Type)=0))


    AND Contacts.Group_1=[Client Group]


    ORDER BY Contacts.Name, DataProfile.Date;`

This produces a list of daily totals by site by day and looks like :

Site.......Date.........Value
Site 1....01/01/13...444.7
Site 1....02/01/13...861.5
Site 1....03/01/13...850.0
etc...

Is it possible to write the query to output as :

Site.....01/01/13....02/01/13....03/01/13
Site1....444.7.......861.5.........850.0
Site2....111.1.......222.2.........333.3
etc...

It would make my life so much easier to have one row per site rather than so many. At the moment I am coding excel to adapt the data - but it's long and not efficient. If I could get SQL to output in this format I would be like some kind of office god !!!

Any help/advise/guidence is welcome :)

Comment: What RDMS and what version of the RDMS are you using?

Comment: If you know the number of dates you will have in advance, then it is possible.  If you don't know the number of dates, then it will take some procedural coding (i.e., to my knowledge it can't be done in a single SQL statement).

Answer (score -1):

What version of SQL are you running?
Can you use PIVOT?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx